# How to analyse a bitmap file in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to now how to analyse a BMP, the easiest way. This is only a little part of a bigger program and I don't really have a lot of time for this. Basically I only need to now the "coordinates" of the pixels which are black and that of the pixels which are white. I have done some research and found the following sites interesting:
[site I](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/CPP/Q_20855407.html), [site II](http://www.programuj.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6568&sid=8dcb4da79304d64144bbe0413715eb1e)

the second one is in polish but the code posted there is understandable. The first one seems to be much more complicated (and working only on windows, which is ok for me but I try to avoid it), the second one is using vcl.h which is a Borland specific header(I use VisualStudio). I would appreciate, any help, suggestions, or links to sites covering that topic.

PS: This is my first post if you don't like the way I asked the question tell me what to do better. If you want additional information please ask.

Here is the code thanks for your help.

```
// read_and_send_bmp.cpp
#include <iostream><\code>
#include <string>
#include "bitmap_image.hpp"

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

char * check(string name_of_bitmap);

int main()
{
    string name_of_bitmap;
    cout << "Name of file: ";
    cin >> name_of_bitmap;
    char * toPrint = check(name_of_bitmap);
    cout << endl << "this is the value of 'toPrint': "<< toPrint;
    /* send
    ...
    */
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

char * check(string name_of_bitmap)
{
    bitmap_image myBitMapImage(name_of_bitmap);
    int size = myBitMapImage.pixel_count();
    char * toReturn = new char[size+1];
        for(int i = 0; i < myBitMapImage.pixel_count(); i++)
        toReturn[i] = 'f';
     int h = 1;
     for(int j = 0, jlen = myBitMapImage.height(); j < jlen; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0, ilen = myBitMapImage.width(); i < ilen; i++, h++)
            {
            if(myBitMapImage.red_channel(i, j) == 0 && myBitMapImage.green_channel(i, j) == 0 && myBitMapImage.blue_channel(i, j) == 0)
            {
            toReturn[(j)*myBitMapImage.width()+i] = 'b';
            cout << "pixel nr." << (j)*myBitMapImage.width()+i << " = b" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
            toReturn[(j)*myBitMapImage.width()+i] = 'w';
            cout << "pixel nr." << (j)*myBitMapImage.width()+i << " = w" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    toReturn[size]='\0';
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you've tried (as in your own code).

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? This is a site for questions about programming languages, other than "how do I do this?" =) We encourage _self-help_ and _self-learning_, with SO filling in the gaps

Comment: Please clarify *the easiest way*.  What analysis functions do you need to apply to the BMP?

Comment: take a look at the OpenCV library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the easiest way to analyze a BMP (bitmap), is convert it into a multi-dimensional matrix with one dimension for each channel (e.g. red, blue, green, alpha, etc.).

Once inside a matrix, you can apply transformations using Matrix Algebra.

There are libraries for converting BMPs into matrices.  Search the web for "library c++ bmp".

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: http://www.kalytta.com/bitmap.h.

Use CBitmap::Load to load the file, then CBitmap::GetBits to get a pointer to an RGBA buffer which is of size 4 x width x height.

White pixels have R = G = B = 255, black ones have R = G = B = 0.